# Static struct initialization in C

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I have a **struct** type as shown below:

```
typedef struct position{
    float X;
    float Y;
    float Z;
    float A;
} position;

typedef struct move{
    position initial_position;
    double feedrate;
    long speed;
    int g_code;
} move;
```

I am trying to **statically** initialize it, but I have not found a way to do it. Is this possible?

Comment: You cannot initialize *types*. You can only initialize *objects*. In your code you are defining *types*.

Comment: what does it mean to initialize statically in C?

Comment: You cannot initialize types, but you may define directly after your type definition a default value macro like `#define position_DEFAULT { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}`. So later on you can 'create an instance' initialized like `position gPosition =  position_DEFAULT;`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It should work like this:

```
move x = { { 1, 2, 3, 4}, 5.8, 1000, 21 };
```

The brace initializers for structs and arrays can be nested.

Comment: Use of static initialization without designated initializers should be considered deprecated, since it's prone to errors if the order of members is changed, etc.

Comment: Similarly, the use of unnamed function parameters should be deprecated, since it's prone to errors if the order of the parameters is changed.

Answer (score 21):

C doesn't have a notion of a static-member object of a struct/class like C++ ... in C, the `static` keyword on declarations of structures and functions is simply used for defining that object to be only visible to the current code module during compilation.  So your current code attempts using the `static` keyword won't work.  Additionally you can't initialize structure data-elements at the point of declaration like you've done.  Instead, you could do the following using [designated initializers](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/strin.htm):

```
static struct {
    position initial_position;
    double feedrate;
    long speed;
    int g_code;
} move = { .initial_position.X = 1.2,
           .initial_position.Y = 1.3,
           .initial_position.Z = 2.4,
           .initial_position.A = 5.6,
           .feedrate = 3.4, 
           .speed = 12, 
           .g_code = 100};
```

Of course initializing an anonymous structure like this would not allow you to create more than one version of the structure type without specifically typing another version, but if that's all you were wanting, then it should do the job.

Comment: and further, `.initial_position` may be initialized as a struct of its own: `{ .initial_position = { .X = 1.2, .Y = 1.3, .Z = 2.4, .A = 5.6 }, .feedrate = ...`

Answer (score 11):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct A {
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct B {
    struct A a;
    int b;
};

static struct B a = {{5,3}, 2};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("A.a: %d\n", a.a.a);
    return 0;
}
```

result:

> $ ./test
>
> A.a: 5

Comment: yeah, didn't see there, but it shouldn't be a problem if he knows how struct initialization works.