# how to set values in constant structure in cuda

Tags: cuda

I have a Structure and wanted to create object of structure as constant. However I couldnot assign value using cudaMemcpyToSymbol. How can I assign value to constant structure in cuda???

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define N 10
struct CDistance
{
    int Magnitude;
    int Direction;
};
__constant__ CDistance constBuf;

__global__ void foo( int *results )
{
    int tdx = threadIdx.x;
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + tdx;

  results[idx] = constBuf.Magnitude;



}

// main routine that executes on the host
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int arr[2] = { 16, 2};
    int *results_h = new int[N];
    int *results_d;


    cudaMalloc((void **)&results_d, N*sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(constBuf.Magnitude, arr[0], N*sizeof(int), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    foo <<< 1, 10 >>> ( results_d );

    //cudaMemcpy(results_h, results_d, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for( int i=0; i < N; ++i )
        printf("%i ", results_h[i] );
        delete(results_h);
}
```

Comment: how is this duplicate to that given in the link. Here I am trying to use structure and create structure object as constant and then assign value to that structure. cudaMemcpyToSymbol(constBuf.Magnitude, arr[0], N*sizeof(int), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    foo <<< 1, 10 >>> ( results_d ); is not copying values in to structure object

Comment: Have you tried to statically initialize the `struct` according to [static struct initialization in c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691187/static-struct-initialization-in-c)?

Comment: Why are you not doing proper cuda error checking?  You'll be a better CUDA programmer if you do, and if you communicate the error information you receive in your question, others will be able to help you more easily.